# Professional certificate for storage systems (Storage Guru?)

Tags: untagged

Network, security, Linux, Microsoft, etc have their own professional certificate courses so anyone interested can learn and test their knowledge through their exams while some employers like to view such certificates as the minimum requirements for job applicants.

My question:

> Is there such a thing like a course for a professional certificate in storage? This course would discuss stuff like the basics, scenarios, troubleshootings, open/propietary system, every commercial offerings etc etc. (do i miss anything?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a couple websites to get you going:

http://www.snia.org/education/certification/

http://storagemonkeys.com/

There are also vendor certifications and they'll be pretty diverse. Some concepts of course build on each other but knowing an EMC isn't going to give you the fundamental knowledge you need to setup a NetApp or Hitachi.

Comment: Your last sentence is spot-on.

Comment: Didn't knew about this... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well you're right of course but mainly because there's not one dominant storage player (although I know many salesmen who'd disagree! ). I rate the [CDCSNDS](http://www.cisco.com/web/learning/le3/le2/le41/le99/le04/learning_certification_type_home_extra_level.html) qualification but a) I would and b) it's a bit long in the tooth to be honest.

The other contributing factor about this is that there's a huge gulf in required expertise in the storage world, from designing and building the largest and most complex systems to creating the odd LUN/mount-point and hopefully not wiping a company's entire data store (you know who I'm talking about).

Comment: Cisco Data Center Storage Networking Design Specialist certainly looks interesting. Thanks!