# How do I learn about professional server storage?

Tags: storage

I need to learn more about current state of storage. I was taking advices from various storage consultants but I would like to be able to engineer server storage myself.

I'm interested in everything from RAID to JBOD to SAN. If there is a book that covers storage basics, it would be perfect. I'm having trouble finding resources on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I've never found storage to be particularly difficult to find reading resources on.

Try using google... Some keywords you might want to include are Storage, SAN , JBOD, RAID, Storage Performance.  Alternatively, search the tags on ServerFault, "Storage", "San", "JBOD", and so on.
I'm not really prepared to do the googling and result aggregation for you.  It's a much better learning experience for you if you learn how best to search the internet for your own results.

Consider it the difference between giving you fish, and teaching you how to fish

Comment: I know how to google but all I find is commercial sites with offers. What I'm looking is more a book than a bunch of loose questions and product descriptions that assume I know all the details.

Comment: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Storage-Area-Networks-SANs-Dummies/dp/0470385138/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1291106687&sr=8-1 Any good?  At 12 quid, it's worth a punt just to see.

Comment: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Using-SANs-NAS-Storage-Administrators/dp/0596001533/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1291106687&sr=8-8

Comment: Also, this question seems to have some valid points about vendor specificity: http://serverfault.com/questions/201707/professional-certificate-for-storage-systems-storage-guru